# Maven plugin to ensure UTF-8 Encoding?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, maven, maven-plugin

Is there a Maven plugin I can use to fail my build if the builder notices a file that is not encoded with UTF-8?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is https://github.com/mikedon/encoding-enforcer

It uses the [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/), and [juniversalchardet](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/) to do the encoding detection.

**UPDATE 2016-10-20:** org.codehaus.mojo has an [extra-enforcer-rules](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/) plugin which introduces a [requireEncoding](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/requireEncoding.html) rule. It uses [ICU4J](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j) for the encoding detection.

Usage is:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <!-- find the latest version at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/ -->
  <version>1.0</version> 
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>require-utf-8</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <requireEncoding>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <includes>src/main/resources/**,src/test/resources/**</includes>
          </requireEncoding>
        </rules>
        <fastFail>false</fastFail>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
      <!-- find the latest version at http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/ -->
      <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I get an error when I run the plugin using configuration from the git site... (Maven v. 3.3.9 + java 7): [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.2:enforce (default-cli) on project: The parameters 'rules' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.2:enforce are missing or invalid -> [Help 1] ..... Rules configuration is identical from github, just copy/paste

Comment: The readme on your fork says to build from mikedon's url, which is confusing, so I built from ericbn but still get the same error? The parameters 'rules' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.2:enforce are missing or invalid... im running via mvn enforcer:enforce ?

Comment: Ok, so i finally got this to work based on info in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827194/maven-enforcer-plugin-missing-or-invalid-rules  THIS IS WHY I HATE MAVEN AND ANYONE WHO CHOOSES TO USE THIS TOOL... you need to set id for the execution do 'default-cli'  AARRRGH BURN IN HELL MAVEN

Answer (score 5):

Good choice on adopting Maven - no doubt you'll soon be a total convert! :)

You may want to look at the [Maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/). As a start you could use the `requireProperty` rule to ensure that the `project.build.sourceEncoding` property is set to UTF-8.

As for checking the actual files themselves (i.e. checking whether someone has committed a non-unicode file), you could [implement your own custom rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) for the enforcer plugin. When this rule is executed, you'd need read all the resources in the project and find some method of detecting the encoding for each (e.g. iconv).

Answer (score 1):

`maven-enforcer-plugin` works well for us.

We need to use [acceptAsciiSubset](https://github.com/mojohaus/extra-enforcer-rules/issues/270) for files without any UTF-8 specific characters or [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), otherwise it complains about `US-ASCII` encoding.

Also the [failFast](https://github.com/mojohaus/extra-enforcer-rules/issues/271) tag needs to be inside `requireEncoding` to list all failing files:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>require-utf-8</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireEncoding>
                                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                <acceptAsciiSubset>true</acceptAsciiSubset>
                                <failFast>false</failFast>
                            </requireEncoding>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```