# Maven enforcer plugin missing or invalid rules

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am trying to setup the enforcer plugin for maven to enforce a minimum Java version. However, whenever I try to run `mvn enforcer:enforce`, I get:

> The parameters 'rules' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce are missing or invalid

Here is the relevant portion of my pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-java</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <requireJavaVersion>
                        <version>(1.7.0-20,)</version>
                    </requireJavaVersion>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also tried replacing the `<requireJavaVersion>` block with `<alwaysPass/>`, in case something was invalid, but it still failed with the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [usage of maven enforcer plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754974/usage-of-maven-enforcer-plugin)

Comment: @acm in my case the solution was the default-cli parameter, part of the accepted answer here. Less obvious in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754974/usage-of-maven-enforcer-plugin

Comment: doesnt work, I always get error Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (default-cli) on project : No rules are configured. Use the skip flag if you want to disable execution.

Comment: [This](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) this is really helpful.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It may be that you are using invalid rule names. Check out the [rules](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html) page.
The rule names are case sensitive.
Though this is not the case here.

---- Edit ----

Note that the POM configuration has an execution ID of `enforce-java` and that execution is bound to the `validate` phase of the lifecycle.  The command `mvn enforcer:enforce` is running a goal, not a phase in the lifecycle. The configuration you provided in the POM doesn't apply to the `enforcer:enforce` goal.

There are two ways to make this work. Which one you choose depends on what you need.

1. If you are just trying to test the enforcer plugin configuration without running the whole build, run `mvn validate`.
2. If the requirement is that `mvn enforcer:enforce` works, then change the execution ID to `default-cli`.

Comment: I was originally using <requireJavaVersion> and <alwaysPass> but when I copied it here I did it incorrectly.  even with the valid rule names I get the same error.

I edited the post to correct this.

Comment: Changing the id to `default-cli` makes `mvn enforcer:enforce` work correctly.  But `mvn validate` always succeeds even if the enforced requirements aren't met.

Comment: You should check your version range for Java you have given. I think you would like to do something like this: ´<version>[1.7.0,)</version>`.

Comment: If you change the id to `default-cli`, then the config will ONLY work if you run `enforcer:enforce` from the command line.  The way you originally had it, the config works when run as part of the lifecycle.  If you want both to work, then you need two executions, one with ID `default-cli` and one with phase `validate`.  Consider reviewing the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html) for an explanation.

Comment: I changed the id back to enforce-java but it still doesn't get run during the validate phase.

Comment: Fixed it.  The issue was that my plugins were nested in a `<pluginManagement>` tag.  It works as expected now. Thanks.

Comment: `default-cli` fixed it for me, thanks. I like how Maven requires hard-to-find arcane incantations to make the simplest things work.

Comment: To be fair, its the `execution` that complicates this configuration. `enforcer:enforce` would also work if you added the configuration to the plugin instead of a specific execution. Something like this:

```<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
     <configuration>
      <rules>
       <dependencyConvergence/>
      </rules>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this precise same error while trying to build vertx workshop project. As it turns out, the error is primarily an enforcer plugin version related issue. This following configuration solved it for me.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M3</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-java</id>
      <phase>enforce</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <requireJavaVersion>
            <version>(1.8.0,)</version>
          </requireJavaVersion>
        </rules>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I was putting the enforcer configuration inside the build part of a Maven profile which was not being built when I ran `mvn validate`. A simple `mvn validate -P correctProfile` fixed it for me. In the end I put it into the parent project of a multi-module application, set the transitive search of bytecode enforcer rule to true: `<searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>` and verified that an incorrect dependency in a child project indeed causes a build failure.